# Google protocol buffer installation failling in windows xp

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to run these commands given in the read me of protocol buffer

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

when I give `./configure`, I get the error

`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it seems like you haven't got to the right directory that has the executable file "configure."

If your goal is to install protocol buffer on Windows, specifically for Java, you can do the following steps:

1. Download 2 files from http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list (get the most up-to-date version)

   - protobuf-2.4.1.zip
   - protoc-2.4.1-win32.zip (this is the pre-compiled file for easy install)
2. Follow instructions in README from the downloaded protobuf

   - Install Apache Maven
   - Follow instructions in README in the downloaded Apache Maven
3. Step 3 is the one that I spent a lot of times since I hadn't read the whole documentation in the first place and did a harder way. I suggest to do step 3B since it takes me 5 minutes instead of waiting to download cygwin.

   - *[DIFFICULT]For compiling binary ourselves, download and Install cygwin (REMEMBER to select gcc)*

     - Run ./configure, make, make check, make install
   - **[EASY] Using pre-compiled binary:**

     - Unzip protoc-2.4.1-win32.zip
     - Place protoc.exe in protobuf-2.4.1\src (notice that this is different than protobuf-2.4.1\java\src . Some people on the net is confused between these 2 files so they'll get "An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "../src/protoc"" exception and have to change the pom.xml file manually. If we place the protoc.exe in the correct folder, we don't have to modify anything as I'm aware of)
     - Place protoc.exe in PATH (i.e. protobuf-2.4.1\src)

   Then, below is just the copy from README file
4. Check protoc by executing "protoc --version"
5. cd protobuf-2.4.1\java (which has the file "pom.xml")
6. run "mvn test", "mvn install", "mvn package"

Should not have any errors

Answer (score 0):

you must run ./autogen.sh first